# Cordova Build App Issues | JDK | Android Target | avdmanager

Tags: java, android, cordova, android-virtual-device

I installed latest version of the following tools:

1. node.js
2. JDK 8
3. Android Studio
4. Cordova

I created an app, however when I try to build for android platform is gives me the following error:

```
    Error: Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8 or greater
```

If I try `cordova requirments`,I get the following response:

```
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
avdmanager: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:213)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:200)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
        ... 5 more
Gradle: installed /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/gradle/gradle-3.2/bin/gradle
```

Any idea what else I can try update or fix due to these errors ?

Comment: guys, were you able to fix this issue? I am having the same error and am totally lost!